# How can I "Rub your head on the roof for __ m (in one game)"?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

In one of the missions for Jetpack Joyride, the primary objective is to rub your head on the roof for __ meters (length varies depending on difficulty). Completing this objective is required to complete the mission and unlock additional missions.

I am playing on professional difficulty so I need to rub my head on the roof for 300 meters to complete the mission objective.

How can I "Rub your head on the roof for __ m (in one game)"?

Comment: Hi Auhona -- it's really difficult to tell what you're asking here. What game are you playing and what issues is it giving you?

Comment: I was pretty sure this was nothing but trolling. How did you guys decipher this into the current question?

Comment: @MennoGouw Loving care and attention.

Comment: @MennoGouw I kinda guessed at what game it was within minutes of seeing it. Just couldn't post anything because I was at work.

Answer (score 23):

In order to complete this mission objective, you need to hold your jetpack **on** so that Barry will stay on the ceiling for the duration of the level. Try to stay on the ceiling at all times, unless there is an obstacle in the way, for the best chance to complete this objective.

Do note however, that staying on the ceiling in a vehicle does not count towards the objective.

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because I can't upvote your [edits to the question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/141980/revisions). That's some _really_ impressive editing there, all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you have to do is stay with your head against the roof for those 300 meters. It doesn't have to be all in a row, you can come down, but it has to be all in one run.

Answer (score 0):

To pass this mission I found it is easier to do it with "gravity belt" gadget. That gadget pulls you faster toward a ground letting drop faster to avoid stuff. And just like everyone else said just keep your head against the ceiling when you are not inside vehicle.